# Doctrine2: Arbitrary join and single table inheritance

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Note: This is an ORM limitation [reported on the project's issue tracker](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2235)

I'm facing an issue building a *DQL* query using the arbitrary join syntax introduced in **Doctrine 2.3** on an entity class which is the root of a hierarchy.

Given these classes:

> A - no inheritance
>
> B1 - abstract, root of a hierarchy, discriminator column is named 'type'

I setup a query builder like this:

```
$qb->select('a.id AS idA, b.id AS idB')
    ->from('\Entity\A', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('\Entity\B1', 'b', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'a.something=b.something');
```

And the SQL Doctrine generates is something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON (a.something=b.something) WHERE b.type IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

The problems is that the where makes the **left join** useless.

Is there a way to force the condition on the discriminator column to be placed in the join? At least that would make it...

Should I fill a bug report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is fixed in Doctrine 2.4

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/2934

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried an inner join instead a left join? The query that you need probably could

```
SELECT a.id, 
       b.id 
FROM   a 
       INNER JOIN b 
               ON ( a.something = b.something ) 
WHERE  b.type IN ( '1', '2', '3' )
```

You can get that changing the function leftJoin by join, or creating the query with the createQuery method for customs queries.

Comment: Well I want to retrieve all the A elements, even those that don't have any B so an inner join wouldn't help. Actually, the current behavior is the same as if I used an inner join because of the where condition on the b.type column.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT a.id, 
       b.id 
FROM   a 
       INNER JOIN b ON ( a.something = b.something ) and b.type IN ( '1', '2', '3' )
```