# Too many joins with Doctrine using "Class Table Inheritance" on a Symfony project

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm working with Symfony and Doctrine and I ended up with the following errors:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1116 Too many tables; MySQL can only
>   use 61 tables in a join`

The main entity (topmost table of the hierarchy) contains a discriminator map of over 61 entities. A "Many-To-Many" association is made over itself, so an Entity can be linked to others as parents or children.

**Here is the Entity Doctrine annotation** :

```
/**
 * Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="entity")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\EntityBundle\Repository\EntityRepository")
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "sub_entity_1" = "\Acme\SubEntityABundle\Entity\E1",
 *      "sub_entity_2" = "\Acme\SubEntityABundle\Entity\E2",
 *      ...
 * })
 */
class Entity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity", inversedBy="parentEntities")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="rel_entity_entity",
     *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="child", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $childrenEntities;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Entity", mappedBy="childrenEntities")
     *
     */
    private $parentEntities;

    /**
     * Get children entities
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getChildrenEntities()
    {
        return $this->childrenEntities;
    }

    /**
     * Set childrenEntities
     *
     * @param ArrayCollection $entities
     */
     public function setchildrenEntities(ArrayCollection $entities)
     {
         $this->childrenEntities = $entities;
     }

     ...
}
```

Whenever I use the Query Builder in a formType to get a list of some classic Entities (which do not even extend the topclass "Entity"), Doctrine will do a left join on every entities in the discriminator map (and generate the General error of MySQL).

**FormType** :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('childrenEntities', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AcmeEntityBundle:Entity',
        'required' => false,
        'choice_label' => 'slug', // slug is defined as a main entity's attribute
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->getSomeEntities();
        },
    ));

    ...
}
```

**EntityRepository** :

```
public function getSomeEntities()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('e')
        ->from('AcmeEntityBundle:Entity', 'e')
        ->where('e.id IN (:ids)')
        // Tried that, doesn't work
        //->andWhere('e INSTANCE OF AcmeEntityBundle:Entity')
        ->setParameter('ids', [53300, 12345]);
}
```

Is there a way to tell doctrine not to make any join? I only need main entity's attribute, such an id or a slug, so I don't need any value from sub classes

Doctrine version is : **2.4**

Some usefull doc I read :

- [Query field of root entity in doctrine (joined) class table inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695371/query-field-of-root-entity-in-doctrine-joined-class-table-inheritance)
- [Doctrine2: Arbitrary join and single table inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860375/doctrine2-arbitrary-join-and-single-table-inheritance)
- http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, big problem because is a [mysql limitation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/joins-limits.html). I don't understand why doctrine is doing the left join if you are not requesting that. If you only need data related to the main entity, them change the select to those specific fields:

```
->select('e.id, e.slug, ...')
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: I tried with `->select('e.id, e.slug)` : it makes correct select but still with every table **joined**. I reproduced that case with a simple case : 2 classes inside a DiscriminatorMap (still _JOINED_ typed). And making a simple form with only one "entity" field :
`public function getSomeEntities()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('e.id, e.slug')
            ->from('AcmeEntityBundle:Entity', 'e');
    }`

Comment: That's weird, well, still you can use the nuclear option, http://doctrine2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#native-sql

Comment: Yeah, I opened an issue on GitHub, let's see : https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5961

Comment: btw, even if doing `->select('e.id, e.slug)` makes correct SQL, it generates another problem : `Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given` because (I guess) id and slug are not enough data to allow Doctrine to rebuild the corresponding Entity. Maybe I would need a Transformer in that case, but that is another topic :)

Answer (score 0):

By the documentation

> Class Table Inheritance is an inheritance mapping strategy where each class in a hierarchy is mapped to several tables.

Here it looks like you have some sort of base class and then a bunch of classes that extends it and add some very different properties to it.

I am not super familiar with the Class table inheritance use but here it looks like there is a difference between what the feature was designed for and how you use it.

Comment: In my classic use case, I indeed use this hierarchy just like you said (_some sort of base class and then a bunch of classes that extends it and add some very different properties to it_). But in a specific use case, I also need to list every slug of these classes. Slug is part of the base class, so I don't need the _very different properties_, thus I do not need all the automatic join crap :)

Comment: Then maybe it's better to have all those class have a one-to-one relationship to a slug class, but it's a bit hard to say without seeing the big picture.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've broken [one of the main rules of Doctrine's CTI](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#id4): not to make an accociation to the class hierarchy. 
In your case, you've done a parent-child association and that's why Doctrine produced too many JOINS. It tried to JOIN all your children entities to the parents, I guess. I think you should avoid doing a parent-child association with CTI on the same entity.